# BIND9 works with an empty configuration

Tags: bind

I'm running BIND 9.11 on Ubuntu 18.04, I have commented all the 'include' statements in 'named.conf' and then issue 'sudo named -g' and I found BIND9 still works unless I add 'view' statement in 'named.conf.default-zones'!
I tested it with nslookup as following:

1. nslookup
2. server 172.20.10.7
3. www.google.com

I got the answer!
Could anyone please tell me why? Or please give me some materials to read?
Thank you in advance!
Wang Hong